# Xcode shows duplicate warning or error information

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Xcode 13.1, I'm not sure if anyone had met this weird behavior. But for me, my Xcode shows duplicate warning or error message to me from some time I'm not sure. It is really annoying.

[image]

[image]

Comment: might have to do something with the SwiftUI framework? I mostly use SceneKit and I have this kind of double indications occasionly (like one out of 10 warnings) - you could probably file this to Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Xcode 13.1 that has been fixed in 13.2(.1)

Comment: Yes, Update fix it. I thought I was in the latest one, though it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Update Xcode 13.1 to 13.2.1 to avoid these internal issues